# Cartesian/parametric equation of a 2v and 3v geodesic sphere

Tags: geometry, geodesic

Well.

I'm looking for the cartesian -or parametric- equation that describes the geodesics of 2V and 3V geodesic spheres. I'm not sure if I'm getting the terminology right, but what I'm looking for, essentially, are equations which I can plug values into, and it will describe for me the skeleton of a geodesic dome. I've tried googling this, but I haven't found anything appropiate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE Shaun ! I am not sure what you mean by 2V and 3V.

Comment: Perhaps you want [the Dome Calculator](http://desertdomes.com/domecalc.html) at the Desert Domes website?

Comment: Rahul: I'm afraid not, I'm looking to 'draw' a geodesic dome programmatically, so that calculator doesn't help.

magma: It's apparently how you distinguish how much you subdivide the triangles making up the dome; 1V is an isocahedron, 2V has more triangles and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

Good reference for the discussion, challenges, mathematics, and some C code is the following book:

"[Divided Spheres: Geodesics and the Orderly
Subdivision of the Sphere](https://www.routledge.com/Divided-Spheres-Geodesics-and-the-Orderly-Subdivision-of-the-Sphere/Popko-Kitrick/p/book/9780367680749)", by Edward S. Popko.